# Rinkeby Network: Get USDT balance issue using web3 js

Tags: web3js, metamask

I am using web3.js and getting balance for rinkeby network in MetaMask. But I am getting always object promise in console. But, I want to get USDT amount from the account.

Please check following code.

```
async function getBalance(contract,accounts) {
    
    contract.balanceOf(accounts[0], function(error, balance){
        contract.decimals((error, decimals) => {            
            balance = balance.div(10**decimals);
            netbalance = balance.toString();
            return netbalance;                                      
        });
    }); 
}

$(document).on('click','#click',async function(){   
    try {
        contract = web3.eth.contract(contractABI).at(contractAddress);
        accounts = await ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_accounts' });
        let balance = getBalance(contract, accounts);
        console.log(balance);
    } catch(error) {    
        if(error.code == 4001) {
            var msg = '<p>Transaction rejected by user.</p>';
        }else{
            var msg = error.message;
        }
    }
});
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are using a very old version of web3. I'd suggest to upgrade to the latest version.

Then you can modify getBalance to use async/await. It will look like this for web3 v1.5.

```
async function getBalance(contract, account) {
    let balance = await contract.methods.balanceOf(account);
    let decimals = await contract.methods.decimals();
    balance = balance.div(web3.utils.toBN(10).pow(decimals));
    let netbalance = balance.toString();
    return netbalance;
}
```

Then you could initialize

```
try {
    let contract = new web3.eth.Contract(contractABI, contractAddress);
    let accounts = await ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_accounts' });
    let balance = await getBalance(contract, accounts[0]);
    console.log(balance);
} ...
```